# How can I find the IP address of connected network in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, networking, windows-phone-8

I am trying to find the **IP** address of connected network in windows phone. I was successful to find out the **IP** address of connected **Wi-Fi**. I have used the following class to find the IP address.

```
public class MyIPAddress
{
    Action<IPAddress> FoundCallback;
    UdpAnySourceMulticastClient MulticastSocket;
    const int PortNumber = 50000;       // pick a number, any number
    string MulticastMessage = "FIND-MY-IP-PLEASE" + new Random().Next().ToString();

    public void Find(Action<IPAddress> callback)
    {
        FoundCallback = callback;

        MulticastSocket = new UdpAnySourceMulticastClient(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250"), PortNumber);
        MulticastSocket.BeginJoinGroup((result) =>
        {
            try
            {
                MulticastSocket.EndJoinGroup(result);
                GroupJoined(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //  Debug.WriteLine("EndjoinGroup exception {0}", ex.Message);
                // This can happen eg when wifi is off
                FoundCallback(null);
            }
        },
            null);
    }

    void callback_send(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    byte[] MulticastData;
    bool keepsearching;

    void GroupJoined(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        MulticastData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MulticastMessage);
        keepsearching = true;
        MulticastSocket.BeginSendToGroup(MulticastData, 0, MulticastData.Length, callback_send, null);

        while (keepsearching)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[MulticastData.Length];
                MulticastSocket.BeginReceiveFromGroup(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, DoneReceiveFromGroup, buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Debug.WriteLine("Stopped Group read due to " + ex.Message);
                keepsearching = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void DoneReceiveFromGroup(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        string str = "";
        IPEndPoint where;
        int responselength = MulticastSocket.EndReceiveFromGroup(result, out where);
        byte[] buffer = result.AsyncState as byte[];
        if (responselength == MulticastData.Length && buffer.SequenceEqual(MulticastData))
        {
            str = where.Address.ToString();
            keepsearching = false;
            FoundCallback(where.Address);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(str);

    }
}
```

So by using the above class I can find the **IP** address of connected Wi-Fi. Now I am try to find the address of network which is connected by **Data Connection**. In my windows phone I goto Settings --> System --> Cellular and turn on data connection **on**.

How can I get the IP address of Cellular Network(Data Connection)? Is there any API for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this ....
it will work fine for many networks unlike your code which will work only on wifi network due to multicast IP

it will provide you the ip address of the phone ...

```
        public static IPAddress Find()
        {
            List<string> ipAddresses = new List<string>();

            var hostnames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
            foreach (var hn in hostnames)
            {
                if (hn.IPInformation != null)
                {
                    string ipAddress = hn.DisplayName;
                    ipAddresses.Add(ipAddress);
                }
            }

            IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddresses[0]);
            return address;
        }
```

Comment: There is a case if I turn on wi-fi and also turn on data connection so How can I identify which IP address(wi-fi or data connection) is getting ?

Comment: Hi I am trying to do this in windows phone 7. I have added same class but I am getting the error on "GetHostNames" method. Is it support in windows phone 7?

Comment: There is no any solution on this ? I can't find the IP address in wp7 ?

Comment: sorry basically i have not worked on wp7 yet i only work wp8 so i dont have any idea about wp7 ...